# How do I create a Visualforce page with fields from a single contact's campaign member records?

Tags: visualforce

I would like to make a Visualforce page with the values from all of a particular custom field on a single contact's campaign member records. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple approach you can take:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:relatedList list="CampaignMembers" />
</apex:page>
```

If you want more control over which fields are displayed, you will need to write some `Apex`. If you want to iterate more than one field you should implement a [Field Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) on `CampaignMember`.

```
public with sharing class CampaignRelatedListExtension
{
    public List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers { get; private set; }
    public CampaignRelatedListExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        campaignMembers = [
            SELECT Campaign.Name FROM CampaignMember
            WHERE ContactId = :controller.getId()
        ];
    }
}
```

Then use a `pageBlockTable`:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="CampaignRelatedListExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Campaign Members">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!campaignMembers}" var="member">
            <apex:column value="{!member.Campaign.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```